# invert colors of Image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIImage color changing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698971/uiimage-color-changing)

I have one image with Grey and white color.I want to change Grey color to white and change white color to Grey through code dynamically. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Better to look out for **[Open CV framework](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port)**, because the thing which you are expecting in already available with this framework.

You can get the source from [here](http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/08/a-complete-ios-opencv-sample-project/)

Sample Code : [Convert RGB to Black & White in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585535/convert-rgb-to-black-white-in-opencv)

[Convert image document to black and white with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594941/convert-image-document-to-black-and-white-with-opencv)

Hope that would give you some new idea about image processing. :)