# Converting an OpenCV Image to Black and White

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

How do you convert a grayscale OpenCV image to black and white? I see a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585535/convert-rgb-to-black-white-in-opencv) has already been asked, but I'm using OpenCV 2.3, and the proposed solution no longer seems to work.

I'm trying to convert a greyscale image to black and white, so that anything not absolutely black is white, and use this as a mask for [surf.detect()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html?highlight=surf#cv2.SURF), in order to ignore keypoints found on the edge of the black mask area.

The following Python gets me almost there, but the threshold value sent to Threshold() doesn't appear to have any effect. If I set it to 0 or 16 or 128 or 255, the result is the same, with all pixels with a value > 128 becoming white, and everything else becoming black.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import cv, cv2
fn = 'myfile.jpg'
im_gray = cv2.imread(fn, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
im_gray_mat = cv.fromarray(im_gray)
im_bw = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im_gray_mat), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
im_bw_mat = cv.GetMat(im_bw)
threshold = 0 # 128#255# HAS NO EFFECT!?!?
cv.Threshold(im_gray_mat, im_bw_mat, threshold, 255, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY | cv.CV_THRESH_OTSU);
cv2.imshow('', np.asarray(im_bw_mat))
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: what is wrong with `im_gray_mat<threshold`

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Step-by-step answer similar to the one you refer to, using the new cv2 Python bindings:

**1. Read a grayscale image**

```
import cv2
im_gray = cv2.imread('grayscale_image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

**2. Convert grayscale image to binary**

```
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

which determines the threshold automatically from the image using Otsu's method, or if you already know the threshold you can use:

```
thresh = 127
im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

**3. Save to disk**

```
cv2.imwrite('bw_image.png', im_bw)
```

Comment: Note: At least in OpenCV 3.1 (and perhaps earlier), `cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` is now `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`. Other than that, the code works perfectly using Python 3.5.

Comment: This may be out of the questions scope, but can you please explain what is the value 128 mean in the first code in 2 if the theshold value is be automatically selected?

Comment: There is nothing special about this value since as you say the threshold is automatically selected. The value is just ignored. See https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp#L1510

Comment: How do you convert the binary obtained into a grayscale image using cv2 ?

Comment: When you use an THRESH_OTSU, automatically THRESH is automatically considered zero

Answer (score 10):

Specifying `CV_THRESH_OTSU` causes the threshold value to be ignored. From [the documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold):

> Also, the special value THRESH_OTSU may be combined with one of the above values. In this case, the function determines the optimal threshold value using the Otsu’s algorithm and uses it instead of the specified thresh . The function returns the computed threshold value. Currently, the Otsu’s method is implemented only for 8-bit images.

This code reads frames from the camera and performs the binary threshold at the value 20.

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    VideoCapture cap; 
    if(argc > 1) 
        cap.open(string(argv[1])); 
    else 
        cap.open(0); 
    Mat frame; 
    namedWindow("video", 1); 
    for(;;) {
        cap >> frame; 
        if(!frame.data) 
            break; 
        cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        threshold(frame, frame, 20, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
        imshow("video", frame); 
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) 
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For those doing video I cobbled the following based on @tsh :

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):pass

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
cv.namedWindow('videoUI', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.createTrackbar('T','videoUI',0,255,nothing)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    vid_gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv.getTrackbarPos('T','videoUI');
    vid_bw = cv.threshold(vid_gray, thresh, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    cv.imshow('videoUI',cv.flip(vid_bw,1))

    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Results in:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

## Approach 1

While converting a gray scale image to a binary image, we usually use `cv2.threshold()` and set a threshold value manually. Sometimes to get a decent result we opt for **Otsu's binarization**.

I have a small hack I came across while reading some blog posts.

1. Convert your color (RGB) image to gray scale.
2. Obtain the median of the gray scale image.
3. Choose a threshold value either 33% above the median

[image]

#### Why 33%?

This is because **33%** works for most of the images/data-set.

You can also work out the same approach  by replacing `median` with the `mean`.

## Approach 2

Another approach would be to take an `x` number of standard deviations (`std`) from the mean, either on the positive or negative side; and set a threshold. So it could be one of the following:

- `th1 = mean - (x * std)`
- `th2 = mean + (x * std)`

**Note:** Before applying threshold it is advisable to enhance the contrast of the gray scale image *locally* (See [CLAHE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_histogram_equalization)).

Comment: could you show the code snippet to (2) obtain the median of a gray scale image?.

Comment: @thewaywewere Yu can use the function available in `numpy` like this: `np.median(gray_image)`

Comment: Thanks for sharing the (2).

Answer (score 5):

Simply you can write the following code snippet to convert an OpenCV image into a grey scale image

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('grey scale image',image)
```

Observe that the image.jpg and the code must be saved in same folder.

Note that:

- `('image.jpg')` gives a RGB image
- `('image.jpg',0)` gives Grey Scale Image.

Comment: Grey scale is not black and white!

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention, if you use `cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY` means every pixel greater than threshold becomes the maxValue (in your case 255), otherwise the value is 0. Obviously if your threshold is 0 everything becomes white (maxValue = 255) and if the value is 255 everything becomes black (i.e. 0).

If you don't want to work out a threshold, you can use the Otsu's method. But this algorithm only works with 8bit images in the implementation of OpenCV. If your image is 8bit use the algorithm like this:

`cv.Threshold(im_gray_mat, im_bw_mat, threshold, 255, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY | cv.CV_THRESH_OTSU);`

No matter the value of threshold if you have a 8bit image.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a two line code I found online that might be helpful for a beginner

```
# Absolute value of the 32/64
abs_image_in32_64 = np.absolute(image_in32_64)

image_8U = np.uint8(abs_image_in32_64)
```