# JavaCV - improve for ocr

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, javacv

Imagine that I want to improve a picture of a thermal impression paper, I am usin JAVA CV but my image gets all black.

I put here an example:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
CvScalar min = cvScalar(100, 100, 130, 0);//BGR-A
CvScalar max= cvScalar(140, 110, 255, 0);//BGR-A
cvInRangeS(image, min, max, imgThreshold);
```

UPDATE:

I am trying to convert the image to grayscale without success.

```
IplImage image = cvLoadImage("example6.jpg");

IplImage imgThreshold = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8, 1);
 cvInRangeS(image, cvScalar(hueLowerR, 100, 100, 0), cvScalar(hueUpperR, 255, 255, 0), imgThreshold);
   cvSaveImage("test1.jpg", imgThreshold););
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to do exactly?

Comment: Thank you. I want to extract the info from the ticket. Imagine that I do have a kfc ticket and I want to extract the fiscal number

Comment: @John Let me ask it in this way - you know that OCR isn't on the level of human vision yet. What makes you think that what you want is possible with the state of the art of current technologies?

Comment: @ sashoalm I already can parse the image, but I am with some issues at some words and numbers, so I am trying to improve the image before OCR.

Comment: Have you tried anything to improve OCR detection?

Comment: " ...I am with some issues at some words and numbers... " Tell us about your issues (these issues). It may be, it's not the image that needs improvement but the algorithm that works on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to improve the accuracy of OCR detection, you must improve the quality of the image you are feeding.

1. You can try **Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization** (I have done the following using python):

[image]

2. You could have applied binary threshold on the gray scale image:

[image]

You might be wondering how I obtained the ***suitable*** threshold value... Well have a look at [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624765/converting-an-opencv-image-to-black-and-white/42434377#42434377) I posted a while ago.

Comment: I am trying to convert the image to grayscale without success.                            
\n
IplImage image = cvLoadImage("example6.jpg");

IplImage imgThreshold = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8, 1);
cvInRangeS(image, cvScalar(hueLowerR, 100, 100, 0), cvScalar(hueUpperR, 255, 255, 0), imgThreshold);
cvSaveImage("test1.jpg", imgThreshold););

Comment: The result image is all black

Comment: Did you calculate the median as given in the answer I posted?