# Binarization of a grayscale image using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm a beginner in OpenCV and I'm trying to binarize an image.

I found this SO post which explains how to do it using Otsu's method:

[Converting an OpenCV Image to Black and White](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624765/converting-an-opencv-image-to-black-and-white)

but when I do this function call

```
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

full code:

```
images = cv2.imread(args["image"])
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(images, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
thresh = 200
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

I get:

```
File "read.py", line 22, in <module>
    (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:1555: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'double cv::threshold(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, double, double, int)'
> THRESH_OTSU mode:
>     'src_type == CV_8UC1 || src_type == CV_16UC1'
> where
>     'src_type' is 24 (CV_8UC4)
```

why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: learn what `CV_8UC1` and `CV_8UC4` mean, from OpenCV docs. then you'll understand. you'll also want to consult numpy docs and learn about `shape`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz so should I convert my image to 8uc1?

Comment: you have a mistake in the cvtColor call. that flag you pass is for imread, not for cvtColor