# OpenCV Save a Mat as Binary (1-bit depth) TIFF

Tags: opencv, tiff, binary-image

Suppose we have a `Mat` after applying the OpenCv's `Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold`:

```
    Mat srcImage = ...;
    Mat binaryImage = new Mat();

    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(srcImage, binaryImage, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
        Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, THRESHOLD_BLOCK_SIZE, 10);
```

When I save the `binaryImage` using `Highgui.imwrite`:

```
boolean isOk = Highgui.imwrite("sample.tiff", binaryImage);
```

Everything is ok except that output TIFF is not actually a binary TIFF - it's a 8-bit depth image:
[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is a similar to the below TIFF format with the 1-bit depth:

[image]

**The question is how to do so with OpenCV?**

Comment: This time I'm facing same issue with opencv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned) single-channel or 3-channel images can be saved by [`imwrite`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/index.html?org/opencv/highgui/Highgui.html).

Comment: How can we achieve this? How can we save 1-bit tiff image in opencv?