# How to convert a colorful image into black and white using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I used a simple approach, iterated over the image and if the intensity is greater than 128 I simply set it to 0 else It is set to 255.

I know there is an existing solutions to my question [Convert RGB to Black & White in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585535/convert-rgb-to-black-white-in-opencv) but I want to know why isn't my solution working.

```
void show_black_white_image(Mat img){
  const char window_with_black_and_white_image[] = "Window With Black & White Image";
  

  MatIterator_<int> it, end;

  for(it = img.begin<int>(), end = img.end<int>() ; it != end ; ++it){
    if(*it > 128) *it = 0;
    else *it = 255;
  }
  imshow(window_with_black_and_white_image, img);
}
```

The output is a blue and black image, I don't know why

Answer (score 3):

From your question I assume your image is **8-bit 4ch**.
That is, the data for each pixel is 4byte.
`*it` is the result of interpreting those 4 consecutive bytes **as a single `int`**.

So, `*it = 255;` means changing pixel value to `(B,G,R,A)=(255,0,0,0);` (if little endian), becomes to blue.

Answer (score 0):

As @fana mentioned earlier I was storing 4 consecutive bytes into an int so was facing this issue.
A solution would be to create an Iterator for type cv::Vec3b as

```
void show_black_white_image(Mat img){
  const char window_with_black_and_white_image[] = "Window With Black & White Image";

  MatIterator_<Vec3b> it, end;

  for(it = img.begin<Vec3b>(), end = img.end<Vec3b>() ; it != end ; ++it){
    if((*it)[0] > 128 && (*it)[1] > 128 && (*it)[2] > 128){
       (*it)[0] = 0;
       (*it)[1] = 0;
       (*it)[2] = 0;    
     } else {
       (*it)[0] = 255;
       (*it)[1] = 255;
       (*it)[2] = 255;
    }
  }
  imshow(window_with_black_and_white_image, img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cv::threshold()` or `cv::inRange()` should have been used.

---

[Here's an official tutorial showing loop access with `MatIterator_<Vec3b>`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html)

Your image's pixel type isn't `int` (4 bytes). You need to put its pixel type there instead.

You say you're using `Vec3b` in your fix. That indicates three bytes per pixel, not four.

So your access using `int` even accessed a byte it was never supposed to.

If you read your picture with `imread()` and no particular flag arguments, it will be `CV_8UC3`, so you need to use `Vec3b`.

If it were 4-channel (likely not), you would use `Vec4b`. In this case, you could also use `int`, if `sizeof(int) == 4`, but then you'd have to peel individual channel values out of the integer.